# Worst case time complexity analysis pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, analysis

Could someone help me out with the time complexity analysis on this pseudocode?
I'm looking for the worst-case complexity here, and I can't figure out if it's O(n^4), O(n^5) or something else entirely. If you could go into detail into how you solved it exactly, it would be much appreciated.

```
sum = 0
for i = 1 to n do
   for j = 1 to i*i do
       if j mod i == 0 then
          for k = 1 to j do
              sum = sum + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop: `O(n)`

Second loop: `i` is in average `n/2`, you could have an exact formula but it's `O(n²)`

Third loop happens `i` times inside the second loop, so an average of `n/2` times. And it's `O(n²)` as well, estimating it.

So it's `O(n*n²*(1 + 1/n*n²))`, I'd say `O(n^4)`. The `1/n` comes from the fact that the third loop happens roughly `1/n` times inside the second one.

It's all a ballpark estimation, with no rigorous proof, but it should be right. You could confirm it by running code yourself.